# VSCode terminal IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio-code

Powershell ISE terminal has the IntelliSense feature. Is it possible to get/enable the same IntelliSense feature in VSCode powershell terminal

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell extension(**PSReadLine**) for VSCode is still in pipeline for the next Enhancement, the teams are working on it should be released soon enough.

From what I read seems like a lot of work before they can get PSReadline to coexist with the PowerShell extension's language.

As per the comment from David Wilson from the discussion

> "PSReadline is not supported in the integrated console at this time. A non-trivial amount of work is needed to make PowerShell Editor Services and PSReadline play nicely together so this could take some time.
>
> Features this will enable:
>
> **1.Ctrl+Arrow keys, etc (keyboard navigation of the input line)**
>
> **2.Syntax highlighting of input text**
>
> **3.Multi-line text input (writing a function definition in the console across multiple lines)**"

You can follow the discussion on

https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/535

Comment: Ok.. cool.  looking forward to see PSReadLine implemented with vscode.

Comment: Glad it helped, would be great if you could also upvote the answer so it would also be helpful to others in the community, Cheers !!